# Receiving an error when calling constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I am receiving this error when I reach this part after the scans in my code:

> Project2_JoshuaLucas[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=java.awt.Dimension[width=350,height=200]]

```
Project2_JoshuaLucas selection = new Project2_JoshuaLucas("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 0.00);

Object source = event.getSource();
if (source == cabin1)
{
  cabin1.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
  cabin2.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin3.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin4.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin5.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin6.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin7.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin8.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin9.setBackground(Color.gray);
  cabin10.setBackground(Color.gray);
  suite1.setBackground(Color.red);
  suite2.setBackground(Color.red);

  System.out.println("Your choice is Cabin 11-1, would you like to designate this as your room?");
  info1 = scan_in.nextLine();
  info1 = info1.toLowerCase();

 if ( info1.equals ("yes") || info1.equals ("y"))
{
   continues=true;   
   System.out.println("Please enter the number of people in your cabin (*Maximum number of people is 2*)");
   cabin_people = scan_in.nextInt();
   scan_in.nextLine();


   while(continues)
   {
     switch (cabin_people)
     {
     case 1:
       System.out.println("There is one passenger within the cabin. (You will pay an EXTRA 45% because of the empty passenger slot)");
       continues=false;
       onepassenger=true;
       break;
     case 2:
       System.out.println("There are two passenger within this cabin.");
       continues=false;
       twopassenger=true;
       break;
     default:
       System.out.println("Please try again. Remember, the maximum amount of passengers allowed is 2.");
       System.out.println("How many passengers are staying within this cabin?");
       cabin_people=scan_in.nextInt();
       scan_in.nextLine();
       continues=true;

 }//Closes the Switch
 }//Closes the while(continues) loop

 while(onepassenger)
 {
   System.out.println("Please state your FIRST name: ");
   fname1=scan_in.nextLine();
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Please state your LAST name: ");
   lname1=scan_in.nextLine();

   onepassenger=false;
   Project2_JoshuaLucas passenger1 = new Project2_JoshuaLucas (fname1, lname1, "", "", "", "", "", 0.00);
   System.out.println(passenger1);
 } //Closes while(1passenger)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That's not an error; it's what `toString()` returns.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm trying to get the first name and last name that got scanned in to be printed inside of the class im making which is passenger 1.

Answer (score 0):

your toString() method is printing everything from your Object data.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Every class in java extends **Object** class:

```
public class Example{ //extends the default class Object

}
```

- The **Object** class has 11 methods [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

  One of them is  **toString()** method

  When you create a class by calling the **toString()**  you are actually using the method from **Object** class  which by default is returning a String which represent the class itself.

---

- Way 1)

If you want to change toString() to return what you want you have to **@Override**[[Override]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) it.That's the way is done in java.So:

```
    public class Example{

        @Override
        public String toString(){

         return "I am naughty";

       }

     }
```

### Mention that when you are using override you hide the method from the   superclass by replacing it with your method.

- way 2)

  Or **you can add your own methods** to class:

  ```
   public class Example{


     public String  getName(){

       return name;
     }


     public  String getLastName(){

       return lastName;

    }
   }
  ```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without creating a getter method or overriding? How do make it so the toString() method prints fname1 & fname2?